Rectified Linear Unit code entering an array separate with commas MARS MIPS
I have a problem with the output of the code. After I enter an array it should return an array with 0 if the number is positve or 1 if the number is negative. Right now I'm entering 1,-2 as an array and the output does not match at all.
This is the code I've been working on.

# ReLU Function
# Input: $a0 = array address, $a1 = array length
# Output: $a0 = address of result array

.data
    input_prompt:   .asciiz "Enter the array (comma separated): "
    result_prompt:  .asciiz "ReLU of the array: "
    comma:          .asciiz ","
    space:          .asciiz " "
    newline:        .asciiz "\n"
    
.text
main:
    # Prompt user input
    li $v0, 4
    la $a0, input_prompt
    syscall
    
    # Read array from user input
    li $v0, 8
    la $a0, 0x10010000 # Assuming the array is stored at 0x10010000
    li $a1, 256       # Assuming the maximum array length is 256
    syscall
    
    # Compute ReLU
    la $a0, 0x10010000 # Address of input array
    li $a1, 256       # Assuming the maximum array length is 256
    la $a2, 0x10020000 # Address of result array
    jal relu          # Call ReLU function
    
    # Display result
    li $v0, 4
    la $a0, result_prompt
    syscall
    
    # Print ReLU values
    la $t0, 0x10020000 # Address of result array
    li $t1, 0          # Initialize index
    
print_loop:
    lw $a0, ($t0)      # Load value from result array
    li $v0, 1
    syscall            # Print value
    
    # Print comma except for the last element
    addi $t1, $t1, 1
    bge $t1, $a1, print_done
    li $v0, 4
    la $a0, comma
    syscall
    
    addi $t0, $t0, 4   # Move to next element
    j print_loop
    
print_done:
    # Print newline
    li $v0, 4
    la $a0, newline
    syscall
    
    # Exit program
    li $v0, 10
    syscall

# ReLU function
# Input: $a0 = array address, $a1 = array length, $a2 = address of result array
# Output: None
relu:
    li $t0, 0          # Initialize index
    
relu_loop:
    # Check if index exceeds array length
    bge $t0, $a1, relu_done
    
    # Load element from array
    lw $t2, ($a0)
    
    # Compute ReLU
    slti $t3, $t2, 0   # Check if element is negative
    beq $t3, $zero, relu_positive
    
    # Element is negative, set result to 0
    li $t2, 0
    j store_result
    
relu_positive:
    # Element is positive, set result to 1
    li $t2, 1
    
store_result:
    # Store result in result array
    sw $t2, ($a2)
    
    # Increment indices
    addi $a0, $a0, 4   # Increment input array address
    addi $a2, $a2, 4   # Increment result array address
    addi $t0, $t0, 1   # Increment index
    
    j relu_loop

relu_done:
    jr $ra


This is what I've tried so far and the output should be 1,0  not a lot of 1
Enter the array (comma separated): 1,-2
ReLU of the array: 1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1

-- program is finished running --


MARS syscall #8 reads a string, which is text or an atray of bytes, carriage return and null terminated.  There is no syscall that will input an array of integers. If you want that you'll have to program that yourself using what syscalls are provided.
